# Limiting display of RDP to 2 monitors instead of 3 when they have different resolutions

Tags: windows, windows-10, rdp

How do I limit the display to only the first two monitors instead of three monitors, while connecting using remote desktop? My first and second monitor have different resolutions.

```
 First monitor: 2560 * 1080 
 Second monitor: 1920 * 1080
```

The following settings in RDP file do not work

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
selectedmonitors:s:0,1
span monitors:i:1
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed two monitors with the same resolution and solved the issue. Looks like with two different resolutions, it is not possible

Comment: мне хватило добавить следующие параметры:
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
selectedmonitors:s:0,1
span monitors:i:1

PS мониторы с разным разрешением